# Why should G-d correct His Creation as He goes?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, theology, parashat-bereishit, creation

THe Torah and the commentaries clearly suggest in several places that G-d corrected His Creation while still in the process:

> וַיַּרְא אֱלֹהִים אֶת־הָאוֹר כִּי־טוֹב וַיַּבְדֵּל אֱלֹהִים בֵּין הָאוֹר וּבֵין הַחֹשֶׁךְ׃
>   God saw that the light was good, and God separated the light from the darkness.
>
> וַיַּעַשׂ אֱלֹהִים אֶת־שְׁנֵי הַמְּאֹרֹת הַגְּדֹלִים אֶת־הַמָּאוֹר הַגָּדֹל לְמֶמְשֶׁלֶת הַיּוֹם וְאֶת־הַמָּאוֹר הַקָּטֹן לְמֶמְשֶׁלֶת הַלַּיְלָה וְאֵת הַכּוֹכָבִים׃
>   God made the two great lights, the greater light to dominate the day and the lesser light to dominate the night, and the stars.
>
> וַיֹּאמֶר יְהוָה אֱלֹהִים לֹא־טוֹב הֱיוֹת הָאָדָם לְבַדּוֹ אֶעֱשֶׂהּ־לּוֹ עֵזֶר כְּנֶגְדּוֹ׃
>   The LORD God said, “It is not good for man to be alone; I will make a fitting helper for him.”

How this phenomenon can be explained?

Comment: The moon being diminished was a correction based on a mistake which the man made, which is a very famous midrash that you probably know. Separating the light from the darkness wasn’t a correction- it was a continuation of creation. First G-d made the light and darkness, and then he separated between the two- no correction. The only correction that I see here that doesn’t seem to be based on a mistake like the moon made is making chava.

Comment: In case the above comment wasn’t understood- it’s a good question, but the first two cases that you bring don’t seem to fit the question. Also, which commentaries suggest that HaShem corrected his creation? I only see actual pesukim

Comment: @Loani *"mistake which the man made*" - which man?

Comment: I meant which the *moon* made not the man

Comment: @Loani So you do agree that for #2 a correction was needed and performed?

Comment: Yes, but there was an obvious reason for it- the moon’s sin. I think the only one that was corrected without an obvious reason is #3

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%A2_%D7%90%D7%92%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%97%D7%96%22%D7%9C/%D7%90%D7%92%D7%93%D7%94_%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%AA

Comment: Just heard a shiur about this; of course Gcd knows what He is doing; the "corrections" happened and are recorded for OUR sake; to teach US something.

Comment: @DannySchoemann That gods also err? That our G-d is more human than we can think of?  That we are so used to this idea of anthropomorphic God that we don't pay attention to those contradictions?

Comment: Where did I say that? I said (or wanted to say) that Gcd purposefully made it look like things are developed in stages. Of course he knew that Adam would eat from the tree, and die, but there is some lesson(s) for us that he was created to live forever and his sin caused death. There are lessons to be learned from Him creating darkness and them separating it from light, instead of creating it "properly" in the first place.